Anime about 3 vehicles merging
Very long shot and I apologise as I have next to no detail, it's an image thats stuck with me since I was a kid so it would have been early to mid 80's. I've tried searching for it before but as I have so little information I've never been able to identify it.
I think it was a film or TV movie but it might have been part of a series. It was anime style which I don't remember seeing a lot of in UK (terrestrial TV).
The scene that sticks with me is of 3 vehicles merging (I think they might have been the heroes) the main vehicle was a concord type plane/spaceship and there was a blue and a yellow vehicle that split in half and attached either side of the main plane.

What do you mean by "I think it was a film or to movie"?

You might want to choose a more descriptive question title, though. It doesn't really matter for the question if it's a long shot or some kind of challenge and doesn't help to describe the movie in question at all.

Sounds a bit like Thunderbirds 2086 (AKA Technovoyager). The team had three main vehicles: TB-1, TB-2 and TB-3

In their combined form, TB-1 would attach itself on top of TB-2, while TB-3 split in two to attach to TB-2's sides.

You can see the whole sequence in the show's intro:




You know I was almost going to put in the description that they may have been a team like thunderbirds but though it sounded foolish, I had no idea this show existed dispite having watched it as a very young child so thank you for helping find this. It's amazing to now know what the show was
